# Initialise array of struct with const fields which don't have a default constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, constants

I want to define an array of structs, but this is not working because it has a const field without default constructor.

Struct is part of an SDK and looks like following:

```
struct SParametricParamDef
{
    const TXString          fUniversalName;
    SResString              fLocalizedName;
    const TXString          fDefaultImperial;
    const TXString          fDefaultMetric;
    EFieldStyle             fFieldStyle;
    short                   fChoicesChcID;
};
```

`TXString` does not have a default constructor. So following is failing:

```
SParametricParamDef *arrParams = new SParametricParamDef[size]; // <= throws compile time exception
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    arrParams[i] = params[i].def; // <= also throws an exception, because operator = is not available
}
```

Is there some way to solve this? I need an `SParametricParamDef*` as a result, because this array is used in the SDK again...

**Info**

In an old SDK version, `const TXSTring` was `const char*` and back then I did not have problems... Now I need to adjust my code to work with the new structures...

Comment: First, it is called a compile error. Second, use a `std::vector`. If you must have a pointer, grab it from the `std::vector`

Comment: did not know this is possible. I read that this is not possible with `std::array` but seems to be possible with `std::vector` though with the data field.

Comment: What is not possible with `std::array`? Either way, `std::array` is not what you want here

Comment: I mixed something up, sorry. You suggest using `std::vector` and use `std::vector::data` to get the underlying pointer, correct? I'm not sure now, if this is save, can I return this pointer from a function or will it run out of scope then? Because this is what I need and that's why I use `new` in my example code...

Comment: Pass the `std:: vector` around and only fetch the pointer when needed. Learn about RAII and how c++ manages memory, `new` is almost always a mistake

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is not primarily about `operator =` but about the fact that you default-constructed an object with `const` members. This will render them immutable and any attempt to modify them, as you are trying in the loop, must fail.
Fortunately, you can use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to initialize the SParametricParamDef objects right inside the vector without taking the indirection of default-construction and assignment:

```
std::vector<SParametricParamDef> arrParams;
for(std::size_t n = 0; n < size; ++n) {
    arrParams.emplace_back(params[n].def);
}
```

This should minimize the amount of copying and comes without the need to modify the `struct` definition.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that you are asking for a `TXString` to be created without directing how it can be initialised. It is difficult to know how to address the problem of creating a `TXString` object since you haven't given a list of the constructors for the class, but as it stands a change would need to be made to the code you've given. Some ways of solving this are as follows:

The most obvious is to add a default constructor for `SParametricParamDef` which initialises the `TXString` objects:

```
struct SParametricParamDef
{
    SParametricParamDef() : fUniversalName(...), ... {}
...
```

Another approach, given that the variables are `const` *might* be to make them `const static`

Say, for simplicity's sake, that the `TXString` object was as follows:

```
struct TXString{
    TXString(char a) : _a(a) {}
    char _a;
};
```

You could then change your declaration of `SParametricParamDef` to:

```
struct SParametricParamDef
{
    const static TXString fUniversalName;
...
```

and then define `fUniversalName` in your implementation file as follows:

```
const TXString SParametricParamDef::fUniversalName('D');
```

Another way might be to wrap a `TXString` object in another object that *does* have a default constructor:

```
struct TXStringWrapper {
    TXStringWrapper() : _s(...) {} // [1]
    const TXString& get() { return _s; }

private:
    TXString _s;
}
```

At [1], you create the `TXString` in whatever specific, non-default way that you care.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an example for using a *placement new*:

```
SParametricParamDef *arrParams = (SParametricParamDef *) new char[size * sizeof(*arrParams)];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    // constructs an object in a pre-allocated memory
    new(arrParams+1) SParametricParamDef(params[i].def);
}
```

You should explicitely call a destructor if it is not trivial before freeing the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    ~SParametricParamDef(arrParams+1);
}
delete[] ((char *) arrParams);
```

This is rather old fashioned because it mimics the initialization of structs in C, but it is the only way I know to build an array of objects that only have non trivial constructors (AFAIK, the `std::vector` way requires copyable or movable objects)

Comment: Technically this answer is correct, but one should use rather `std::vector` which internally will  use placement-new as well.

Comment: @Jodocus: I agree that is not very idiomatic, and I use it only in desperate use cases, but it can help with weird classes.

Comment: This seems the only solution to my problem. Just to make sure, the resulting array will be able to be passed back by a function and will live as long as I don't manually destruct it (which is what I need, the SDK will keep this array until it destructs my plugin) which would not be true if I pass the std::vector::data pointer to the SDK, right?

Comment: @prom85: a `std::vector` may be simpler to use, it you can keep it alive, for example if you can declare it in your main or if you can make it static if you only need a single one. This way is lower level, but depends only of correctly destroying the array pointer.